# $\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{\mathcal L (f^{-1}([x,x+h)))}{h}$ where $f^{-1}$ is the preimage of a Lipschitz function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Motivated by the question [Compute derivative of $g(x)=\mathcal L(\{y \in [a,b]: x >f(y)\})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3048453/compute-derivative-of-gx-mathcal-l-y-in-a-b-x-fy), I'd like to ask:

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. How can one compute the limit $$\lim_{h \to 0^+}  \frac{\mathcal L(f^{-1}([x,x+h))}{h},$$
where $f^{-1}$ denotes the pre-image of $f$; $\mathcal L$ the Lebesgue measure; and 
assuming only that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous?

In the special case $f$ monotone, the question is much easier, since 
$$f^{-1}([x,x+h)) = [f^{-1}(x), f^{-1}(x+h)).$$

Comment: Why is that not nonsense?  Given a set A of real numbers and a nonzero h, what is A/h?  If for all nonzero h, g(h) is a set of real numbers, what is the limit of g(h) as h approaches zero?  What happens when h is negative?

Comment: @WilliamElliot I ment the measure of the set, of course. There was a typo.

Comment: Limit as h -> 0 indicates h can be positive or negative.   For h < 0, [x,x+h) is empty, giving a liminf of 0.  Thus, if there is a limit, it has to be zero.

Comment: @WilliamElliot I've edited the question to address this ambiguity: we consider only $h \to 0^+$.

Comment: @Hiro you are probably after Lebesgue differentiation theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem